# Добавление виджета через .xsl файл (UMI)

Tags: cms, виджет, umi

Здравствуйте!

Хочу добавить код Jivosite на сайт с UMI. Шаблоны имеют формат .xsl
Стандартное добавление

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="xxx"></script>
```

ломает шаблон

Не особо понимаю, как это сделать с файлами данного формата. Уже добавлен внутренний скрипт с помощью

```html
<xsl:template match="result[page/@is-default = '1']" mode="scripts-additional">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{$template-resources}js/portfolio_filter.js{$template-version}"></script>
    </xsl:template>
```

Знаю, что сам javascript можно добавлять через xsl:text, но как быть с ссылкой на скрипт?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Часто проблема в амперсанде. В xsl он должен быть экранирован: `&amp;`